# Getting data from Firebase not displaying with React JS?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got the below react js cod running with no errors but not sure why it's not displaying anything from the database in the `<li>` element.

When I console log it in the ComponentWillMount, it pulls the data correctly.

**App.js**

```
    class FirebaseDB extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { messages: [] };
      }
      componentWillMount(){
        let messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');
        messagesRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
          let message = { text: snapshot.val(), id: snapshot.key };
          console.log(message);
        })
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <ul>
              { /* Render the list of messages */
                this.state.messages.map( message => <li key={message.id}>{message.text}</li> )
              }
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FirebaseDB />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never setting the state to contain messages so it would never render. You could try

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { messages: [] };
}

componentWillMount(){
  let messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');
  messagesRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
    let message = { text: snapshot.val(), id: snapshot.key };
    this.setState({
      messages: [...this.state.messages, message],
    });
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In react, if you want something to display on screen you need to put on `state`. Now you do have a `messages` array on your `state`, but the data which you are retrieving from firebase is not getting added to `state`, and as a result nothing is getting rendered.

I am not familiar with firebase per se, but I imagine the basic idea should be something like this.

```
componentWillMount(){
        let messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');
        messagesRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
          let message = { text: snapshot.val(), id: snapshot.key };
          const messages = [...this.state.messages]; // copy state so not to mutate
          messages.push(message);
          this.setState({messages}); // this will tell react to re-render with the newly added data
          console.log(message);
        })
      }
```